# C# Convert space separated byte array integers into list of integers

Tags: c#

I have the following numbers which I enter into the console on a single line with spaces:

```
4 20 3 3 1
```

I read this line in and assign it to a string variable. Using `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` I convert the string to an array of bytes.

How can I split the array of bytes into integers, by removing the spaces and adding the integers to a list?

For example, the above numbers would be converted to the list `[4, 20, 3, 3, 1]`.

Comment: You don't need to convert the string in an array of bytes. Just split the string and add each single substring to your list with a conversion

Comment: I understand how to do that. However, part of the task is to have the input encoded as ASCII characters which means I have to have it as an array of bytes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What is the purpose to have NUMBERS (digits) encoded as ASCII characters?

Comment: If you get your input in string variable, you no longer have ASCII, you have Unicode/UTF-16. Converting to ASCII and back is a bit silly. `Console.Read()`?

Comment: @phosphenes, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `.Split(" ")` on your input string and you will get array of strings you need.

Than you need to convert them to int. In case you are sure your input comes in that way, you can use linq:

```
string[] split = input.Split(" ");
List<int> values = split.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but, I need this for a byte array where there's spaces in between the integers.

Comment: Of course an input like _1 test 4 notanumber 6_ results in an exception

Comment: @Steve: that is why I wrote " In case you are sure your input comes in that way", otherwise one would need to use `int.TryParse`.

Comment: @phosphenes: What byte array do you need? Representation of what should that byte array be? Of int[] with four values [4, 20, 3, 3, 1] or of a string "420331"? Maybe you could specify better what you need as a result, since you write "_...would be converted to the list [4, 20, 3, 3, 1]_"

Comment: @Edin Okay, so  to clarify: the numbers I am entering into the console to be read as a line is "4 20 3 3 1" with spaces included. This is read as a string. This string is then ASCIIEncoded which makes an array of the following bytes [52, 32, 50, 48, 32, 51, 32, 51, 32, 49] representing the decimal value of each character. I would like to add the integer values of those ascii values to a list but removing the spaces.

Comment: You could remove ascii for space from the array with `yourByteArray.Where(x => x != 32).ToArray()` or `yourByteArray.Where(x => x != ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(" ").First()).ToArray()`. But why just not do the string split before you convert it to byte array in the first place?!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Added solution with `byte[]` as the only problem argument

I have no idea why you can't just take your string and get the things done but here is a solution with byte array from ascii symbols of that string.
Pay attention to any other non-digit-or-whitespace characters and int32 overflow.

```
List<byte[]> splitResult = new List<byte[]>();
IEnumerable<byte> bytes = new byte[] { (byte)'1', (byte)'2', (byte)' ', (byte)'5', (byte)'4', (byte)' ', (byte)' ' }; // <- this should be your bytes
while (bytes.Any())
{
    byte[] oneNumberBytes = bytes.SkipWhile(x => x == ' ').TakeWhile(x => x != ' ').ToArray();
    if(oneNumberBytes.Count() > 0) splitResult.Add(oneNumberBytes);
    bytes = bytes.SkipWhile(x => x == ' ').SkipWhile(x => x != ' ');
}

var result = splitResult.Select(sr => sr.Aggregate(0, (seed, asciiDigit) => seed * 10 + asciiDigit - '0')).ToList();
```

**If it is possible to restore initial string:**

Use `string.Split` method.

```
Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    var integers = input.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
}
```